# removing embedded documents by ObjectId

Tags: mongodb

I am only able to remove (pull) embedded documents (here "items") one at a time.

In my example, "toRemove" is an array of ObjectIds (of cart.items).

```
 db.collection('users').updateOne(
    { _id: new ObjectId(this._id) }, 
    {$pull: {'cart.items': {'productId': toRemove}}}
  )
```

This is not working.

But if I do `toRemove[0]`, it will only remove the first document.
How can I remove them all at once ?

Comment: Please add your schema so that we can help you better.

Comment: mongodb is schemaless, so what do you mean ?

Comment: I know mongodb is schemaless, but people often use schemas just to insure the structure of their collection/documents. Thats why i asked. In simple way, can i see your document structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the special "$in" property, to delete all "items" whose "productId" is inside "toRemove" array :

```
return db.collection('users').updateOne(
    { _id: new ObjectId(this._id) },
    {$pull: {'cart.items': {'productId': { "$in": toRemove }}}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `$pullAll` instead of `$pull` to remove all matching instances from an array.

```
db.collection('users').updateOne(
    { _id: new ObjectId(this._id) }, 
    {$pullAll: {'cart.items': {'productId': toRemove}}}
  )
```

Read more about [$pullAll here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/)

Comment: $pullAll is not working. It accepts an array. `$pullAll: [...]`

Comment: `{ $pullAll: { <field1>: [ <value1>, <value2> ... ], ... } }` .   I do not want to pull from the main collection. I want to pull embedded documents.